# Angular 5: Use Component of one Module into the Other module

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two Modules in my src folder lets say Module1 and Module2 (so basically both the modules in the same level no parent module for the two)
In my Module 2-- I again have One Module lets say Module2Child which consist of multiple components

My Requirement is to Use One Component which is in the Module1, in the Component of the Module2Child whose parent module is Module2.

I did try to export the component of the Module1 (in **module.ts** file) and  Import the Module 1 in Module 2 but it's not working saying unknown selector

Comment: Any code to debug?

Comment: Please include in the question the code of the modules where you import/export the component.

Comment: So you want to use two module in your project?

Comment: yes there are multiple modules.

Comment: You can club shared components into a module and import this module in the target modules.

Comment: Have you tried to import Module1 in Module2Child?

Comment: Have you tried to import Module1 in Module2Child? I tried to import Module 1 component into module 2